# await function doesn't seem to be waiting

Tags: javascript, server, async-await, client

I'm trying to build a simple login then redirect but the await function doesn't seem to work. When I add in a window.alert between each awaits then it does work. Please help

Client:

```js
      async function submitLogin(){

          var email,pass;

          email=$("#inputUser").val();
          pass=$("#inputPassword").val();         
          
    try {
     const result = await fetch("/login", {method:"POST", headers:{"content-type":"application/json"}, body: JSON.stringify({'email':email, 'pass':pass,}) });
     const login = await result.json();

     if(login.success === true) {
    window.location.href="/admin";
     }
     else {
    window.alert("incorrect login info");
     }
    } catch (e){
   console.log(e);
    }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="submitLogin()">Sign In</button>
```

Server:

```js
app.post('/login', async (req,res) => {

 sess = req.session;
 sess.email = req.body.email;

 let result = {};

 try{
  const pass = await checkUserPass(sess.email);
  if ( JSON.stringify(pass[0].password) == JSON.stringify(req.body.pass) ){
   result.success = true;   
  }
  else{
   result.success=false;   
  }
 }
 catch(e){
  result.success=false;  
 }
 finally{
  res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
 }
 
});
```

I can see this line displaying console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); on the server console.

Comment: Submit buttons submit so cancel the default submit action.

Comment: @epascarello Only if it's in a form.

Comment: @epascarello just tried removing it, didn't solve the problem. I hosted it on AWS btw. on my local host this code works but not on AWS.

Comment: Edit: i added a try-catch block, and I noticed it's giving me a TypeError: Failed to fetch.but if i add in a window.alert in between the fetch and await result.json() line then the code works.